# How to use alias of cordova file plugin?

Tags: android, file, cordova, filesystems, html5-filesystem

In the doc https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md whe have this:

> Android
>
> - files: The application's internal file storage directory
> - files-external: The application's external file storage directory
> - sdcard: The global external file storage directory (this is the root
>     of the SD card, if one is installed). You must have the
>     android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to use this.
> - cache: The application's internal cache directory
> - cache-external: The application's external cache directory
> - root: The entire device filesystem

So, I put this code:

```
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 10*1024*1024, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.sdcard.getFile(path, { create: false }, fileExternExists, fileExternDoesNotExist);
    }, getFSFail);
```

It's not working, but with "root" it works. So, how to use it ?

Comment: Did you do this `You must have the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to use this.`

Comment: Yes of course. When i use "root", files are in sdcard; because she is mounted. But i need to put two different files in internal and external (sdcard), and test if she is available.